# OpenAI ChatGPT API - using sensor data

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have done a python program using the `openai.ChatCompletion.create` to interface to the ChatGPT API.
I am using a `messages` with two roles: `user` with the user prompt as `content`, and `assistant` loaded with current sensor data as `content`, which I get from a set of sensors using MQTT. The sensor data is original JSON, but I formatted it like this:

```
Temperature: 22.07 ºC
Humidity: 62.64 %RH
TVOC: 0 ppb
CO2: 400 ppm
PM1: 0 µg/m3
PM2.5: 0 µg/m3
PM10: 1 µg/m3
```

My idea is to use a clear language to ask `What is the temperature?` and `What is the dew point?` and expect ChatGPT to just give me the first and calculate the second based on the temperature and humidity available in the data.

I don't want to train a model, since the data changes constantly.

Is there a way to feed sensor data to ChatGPT API?
(I have also tried with role `system`, btw)

Comment: Ok, this might not be the right way, but I got it working by adding the sensor data to my prompt behind the scene, like so: `final_prompt = f'Based on this info: {sensor_data}, can you help with this question: {prompt.capitalize()}'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to figure it out with some trial and error:

My API call look like this:

```py
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            temperature=0.6,
            messages=[
                {
                    "role": "system",
                    "content": "You are a helful assistant that helps with sensor data as provided (temperatures all in ºC, humidity in %RH, light in lux and cloud base in meters). You can assist with calculating other values based on the sensor data. You can put the sensor data into context.",
                },
                {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
                {"role": "assistant", "content": sensor_data},
            ],
        )
```

The `prompt` is from HTML input, such as **"Is it dry?"**

The `sensor_data` is a text string with the data in a flat format like this:

```
Temperature: 15.21
Humidity: 82.97
Dew Point: 12.34
Heat Index: 14.96
Wet-Bulb Temperature: 13.27
Cloud Base: 350.38
Cloud Temperature: 11.77
Ambient Light: 30
UV Index: 0.02
```

The response to the above question looked like this:

```
Based on the provided data, the humidity is relatively high at 82.97%RH, which suggests that the air contains a significant amount of moisture. However, without additional information, it is difficult to determine if the conditions are considered dry.
```

The `sensor_data` variable is updated every 5 seconds from a MQTT server, but that could be from anywhere.